# Google spreadsheet API v4 editor access

Tags: node.js, api, google-sheets-api

i want to know if there is any way of adding some email as editor to a google spreadsheet via API in NODEJS.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about your situation. I think that more information is required to be added in your question. For example, you are the owner of the Spreadsheet? And you want to create a permission with an user's email? For example, how do you want to create the permission? Use googleapis of Node.js? Or use the request module? In that case, you can retrieve the access token? How about them?

Comment: I have the same doubts as @Tanaike regarding your question but I wild guess tells me that yiu might be looking for something like granting editor access to a user with the API. To achieve this you would not need the Sheets API but the **Drive API** instead [creating a Permissions request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) for that file (check the link for info in the documentation). **Is this what you are aiming for?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use drive API to share the access.

```
   import { google } from 'googleapis';
   
   const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: yourAuthClient });

   drive.permissions.create({
        fileId: yourSpreadsheetId,
        resource: {
            type: 'user',
            role: 'writer',
            emailAddress: 'example@abc.com',
        },
    });
```

Check out this official documentation for more details https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing

If you are new to googleapis, I found this article helpful. https://bretcameron.medium.com/how-to-use-the-google-drive-api-with-javascript-57a6cc9e5262